# pandas dataframe count all x of unique y

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am currently working with pandas daraframe. Right now I want to count all values x of every y. So example: For every state I have I want to count the number of cities.

I tried something like this, but I know this is not the right syntax but I do not know how to do it right:

```
df['sumCity'] = df[['STATE'].unique()df['CITY']].count()
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df['sumCity'] = df.groupby('STATE').CITY.transform('nunique')
```

Comment: Always doing it a bit better eh? ;)

Comment: @AlexG I appreciate the compliment

Comment: thanks! Can you tell me why I can use city without any brackets and ' ' (string marks)? How do you call that call?

Comment: @threxx because `pandas` makes it convenient in certain circumstances.  `df.groupby('STATE')['CITY'].transform('nunique')` is equivalent.  pandas attaches an `attribute` with the name `CITY` to the `groupby` object.  That is how it is possible.

Comment: Nice + 1 @piRSquared.  Can you please describe how `transform` is being used here?  I'm still learning how to use it.

Comment: @ade1e thx.  `transform` broadcasts aggregated results across the entire group.  In this case, State 'XYZ' might have 102 unique Cities.  However, the original object has a row for each State/City.  Rather than return a single row for each state, transform returns a row for each State/City with 102 repeated for every City in State.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to do a `groupby`. Something like this:

`group = df.groupby('STATE')['CITY'].count()`

And then map this result to a new column using a dictionary:

`df['sumCity'] = df['STATE'].map(dict(group))`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your y, but you can transform your y into class series and using the class value_counts() as below:

```
pandas.Series(y).value_counts()
```